# How to perform a likelihood ratio test for nested distributions?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I would like to perform a ln-likelihood test to compare nested distributions? E.g. Gaussian and Student's.

Does anyone know how it works or knows how to code it? I did not find any function performing it automatically and using `FindDistribution`does not provide the selection for certain distributions. (just gives the results for best fitted once).

Thank you in advance!

Best regards
Alex

Comment: This is rather a math stuff. Up to Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test , the Wilks' theorem is applied in many cases. That can be programmed in Mathematica.

Comment: Is someone able to code it or do you know where I could find hints on that? is there a separate forum here?

Comment: See http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLikelihood.html for more info. Good luck!